# It's/this is my dream being

Tags: demonstrative-pronouns, extraposition, expletive-pronoun

1. **It**'s my dream being on a TV show like this.
2. **This** is my dream being on a TV show like this.

Are they both correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. Rewrite this way:

> ```
> It's my dream to be on a TV show like this.
>
> This is my dream: to be on a TV show like this.
> ```